# Android Kernel TCP implementation

Tags: android, kernel, tcp

I have been working with TCP/IP for a couple of years at the protocol level (debugging issues with connection establishments, computing throughput, etc) and want to explore the protocol at the source code level. My questions are:

1. How much has the TCP/IP stack on Android changed since 4.4BSD?
2. What congestion control mechanism is currently used?
3. Where can I find the source; is [this](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-3.10/net/ipv4/) an appropriate place?